# Continue the program in short if statement

Tags: node.js

I want to check if file is exists, and if not, display an error and terminate the program. if it is exists, just don't do anything. Continue the program.

**Should I use `null` for that ?**

```
!fs.existsSync(args['file']) ? console.error(`${args['file']} is not exists!`) : null;
```

Comment: You want to continue ? when `fs.existsSync(args['file'])` is false ?

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I want to terminate the program if the file is not exists.

Comment: I would suggest using normal `if` `else` in this case return whatever you like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just write it like this:

```js
fs.existsSync(args['file']) || (console.error(`${args['file']} is not exists!`), process.exit(0));
```

**Example**

```js
const a = 'a';

a === 'b' || console.log('a is not b');
```

**Note**

If you want to `return` after the `console.log`, you must use `if` statement.

```js
if (!fs.existsSync(args['file'])) {
    console.error(`${args['file']} is not exists!`);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain? because as far as I know `||` equals to `or` in other languages.

Comment: if `fs.existsSync(args['file'])` is truthy, it will not evalute the next expression. if it is falsy, it will evalue the next expression.

Comment: just think about `a || b`. if a is true, we dont check whatever is b. but if `a` is `false` we check if `b` is true. it's the same logic

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, just try that, i always use the above expression

Comment: How can I terminate the program if the file is not exists?

Comment: @harabatahat, i think you have to use `if` statement in your case. it will be better

Comment: Okay. I accept the answer because it is answers my **first** question.

Comment: i updated answer, you can exit without using if too